# Name of a multiarmed bandit with only some levers available

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits, contextual-bandits

In order to model a card game, as an exercise, I was thinking of an elementary setting as a multiarmed bandit, each lever being the distribution of expected rewards of a specific card.

But, of course, the player only has some cards in the hand each round, or, equivalently, for a given round, it has available a number $n$ of arms randomly selected from the total number $N$ of levers.

Is this just a "contextual bandit" or has it some specific, narrower, name that I could use to look up in the literature?

Comment: To clarify, is there only one state of the game? Can you only select 1 card?

Comment: Yep, habitual game mechanics: you have received $n$ random cards from an stack of $N$, you can play one. In some cases, (eg bridge) perhaps even less than $n$. Seems contextual, but very particular.